# Source server public key not getting copied to another target server

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

I am trying to access the two target Linux systems by copying the same `id_rsa` public key from my same USS source server where I generated it. I am able to copy the generated key to one target system and access it via SSH without it prompting for the password.  But when I attempt to copy the same `id_rsa` pub to another target system which I want to access in the same manner, it is not copying the key at all.

I did the following:

- I navigated to the `.ssh` folder of the home path of my USS source server and executed the copy command like this:

  ```shellsession
  (Ussserver)::/u/ussuserid/.ssh: >cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh target1@servername 'cat > ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
  ```
- It prompted for password and then it copied the key to the target system 1 and I was able to login into the target1 system via ssh without password.
- I again navigated to the `.ssh` folder of the home path of my USS source server and executed the copy command for the second target server:

  ```shellsession
  (Ussserver)::/u/ussuserid/.ssh: >cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh target2@servername 'cat > ~/.ssh/authorized_keys #I pressed "Enter" here

  >
  ```

It simply comes to the next line without doing anything. It did not prompt for the password for the second target server like it prompted for the first target system. Only a greater than symbol (`>`) is the response.

It did not copy the key to the target2 server and I am not able to SSH without using password. I also checked for permissions and everything.

What could be the reason for what is happening?

Comment: In both commands you have an uneven number of single quotes, so _both_ commands should have given you the secondary prompt (a `>` usually) to signal that more text was needed to finish the command (in this case, to close the single-quoted string).  Can you verify that the commands that you show are the actual commands that you wrote, without annotating the commands or editing them in any way (which you have obviously done).

Comment: Both of my commands are exactly the same, I mean the syntax, and the first command worked but the second command did not. I cross checked again and again. Could there be some other reason?

Comment: Note that the first command, `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh target1@servername 'cat > ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, contains a un-closed string, so there is no chance that this would have worked.

Comment: Yes Sorry.. I closed this with the single quote and now it worked. But however, when the public key copy was successful, it is still prompting for the password, which it shouldn't. The fist target system wasn't prompting for password and it allowed to login straight away, but the second target system doesn't. Are two target servers allowed to have the same public key from one source server? I see some threads in the internet saying its allowed, but then it is prompting for password. Do you have any idea why this happens? any suggestions or hints would be greatly appreciated. Thanks,

Comment: You will need to ensure that the permissions and ownerships on the ".ssh" directory and the "authorized_keys" file on the second system are set correctly. Compare with your first system.

Comment: I checked the permissions and authorizations and everything by comparing with first target system. But still it is prompting for the password.  Is there anything else I might be missing out?

Comment: Is `(Ussserver)::/u/ussuserid/.ssh: >` the prompt?

Comment: Please [fix the code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/772834/edit) in your question so it shows exactly what you entered. At the moment the commands are _still_ syntactically invalid. We shouldn't have to guess what you might or might not have really run.